# Get user roles from oidc client

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, oidc-client

I am using oidc-client for my authorization in my app using angular and asp net core 3.1

How can I get the user roles from asp net thru oidc client?

Comment: Do you use IdentityServer4?

Comment: One thing I didn't notice, Do you mean, see "UserRoles" in, angular? or You see the "UserRoles" in the oidc client.
(Role Based Authorization in angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> mUserManager;

        public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            mUserManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await mUserManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

            IList<string> roles = await mUserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            IList<Claim> roleClaims = new List<Claim>();
            foreach (string role in roles)
            {
                roleClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }

            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        }

        public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
...

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
                    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

...
```

Angular oidc-client:

[image]